# How to change select option programmaticaly in bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3 text-white" id="materialType" onchange="typeChange('materialType')" style="background-color: transparent;border: none">
          <option value="Material Type">Material Type</option>
          <option value="All">All</option>
          <option value="Mud">Mud</option>
          <option value="Cloth">Cloth</option>
          <option value="Thread">Thread</option>
          <option value="Jute">Jute</option>
          <option value="Cotton">Cotton</option>
          <option value="Can">Can</option>
          <option value="Bamboo">Bamboo</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
```

When I refresh the page, the selected value in the `typeChange` function goes back to the first option which is `Material Type`. How can I change this after refreshing the page?

typeChange function

```
function typeChange(type)
    {
        //alert('type change'); 
        var typeValue = document.getElementById(type).value;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'typeChange.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:
            {
                type: type,
                typeValue: typeValue
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                window.location.href = 'test.php?id=2';
                //$(type).select(typeValue);
            },
            error: function(data)
            {
                //alert('signup error');
                console.log(data);
            }            
        });
    }
```

I'd like to do this: `$(type).setValue(typeValue);` 
**Edit 1**

I tried doing

```
window.location.href = 'test.php?id=2';
$(type).val(typeValue);
```

but doesn't seem to work.

**Edit 2**

I've also tried

```
window.location.href = 'test.php?id=2';document.getElementById(type).value = typeValue;
```

But that doesn't work either.

**Edit 3**

I have also used the select option value in SESSION
`$_SESSION['materialType']`

**Edit 4**
My select option is in the navber

[image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SA0X.png)

Comment: Try `$('select').val(typeValue)`

Comment: You have to store the selected value somewhere. Could put it in session or sessionStorage and check session for it then if it exists add script to set value

Comment: @NenadVracar I try your solution but failed. see my edited part.

Comment: @charlietfl see my edited question. I have that value in session. but I can't add.

Comment: Need to understand that it will have nothing to do with `typeChange()`. All code in current page is lost when you do page reload. You need a separate code block to run on page load and some conditional that would pass `$_SESSION['materialType']` to javascript variable or that sets `selected` directly in the `<option>` html using php

Comment: If your `select` id is **materialType**, it is not clear to me why you are trying to update `$('select')`. Shouldn't you change this to `$(materialType).val(typeValue) = <whatever>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process flow thinking needs adjusting. You can't set the value inside the `$.ajax` because you are reloading the page. None of the state from current page load is saved by browser for the next load

That means you need to set the value on the next page load

Assuming the main page is a php file you need something like the following:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $type = isset($_SESSION['materialType']) ? $_SESSION['materialType'] :'';// default to empty string or whatever value you want
?>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#materialType').val('<?php echo $type ?>');
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's just by doing this with jquery:

```
$('#selectid').val(variable);
$('#selectid').trigger('change');
```

of course, the 'variable' i put there is the value='' in the select, and must be equal to one option value.